# jquery print dialog box and webmethod

Tags: jquery, printing, webmethod

I am having a problem with jquery, webmethod and printing.

I my jquery code:

```
 $("#PrintBtn").click(function () {
            $("#printDialog").dialog({
                modal: true, autoResize: true, height: $(window).height() - 10, width: '90%',
                buttons: {
                    "CANCEL": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "PRINT ALL": function () {
                        $("#ProcessMsg").dialog({ modal: true, width: 320, height: 200 });
                        FillFe(function () {
                            PageMethods.ProcessPrintRequest(null, $("#hidPDF").val(), FreeEditFields, CreatePostItObjectArray(), function (link) {
                                printResult(link);
                                $("#ProcessMsg").dialog("close");
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    "PRINT SELECTED PAGES": function () {
                        if (SelectedPages.length > 0) {
                            $("#ProcessMsg").dialog({ modal: true, width: 320, height: 200 });
                            FillFe(function () {
                                PageMethods.ProcessPrintRequest(SelectedPages, $("#hidPDF").val(), FreeEditFields, CreatePostItObjectArray(), function (link) {
                                    printResult(link);
                                    $("#ProcessMsg").dialog("close");
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                });

                            });
                        }

                    },
                    "UNCHECK": function () {
                        $(".checkPrint").prop("checked", false);
                        SelectedPages = new Array();
                    }
                }
                , open: function () {
                    SelectedPages = new Array();
                    $("#BookMenu").fadeOut(500);
                    BookMenuShow = false;
                    // $(".checkPrint").prop("checked", false);
                    justShow = false;
                    currentPrTn = PageIndex;
                    //Popluate the chapter box 
                    $("#slChapters").empty();
                    for (var ch = 0; ch < chaptsAndPages.length; ch++) {
                        var chPg = chaptsAndPages[ch].split(",");
                        $("#slChapters").append($("<option></option>")
                                        .attr("value", chPg[0])
                                        .text(chPg[1]));
                    }
                    PopulatePrintBoxEx();
                }
            });
        });
```

My webmethod code

```
      [WebMethod(true)]
    public static string ProcessPrintRequest(string[] selected, string PDFName, List<FreeEditField> freeEditFields, List<PostItNote> PostIts)
    {
        string pdfName = PDFName + ".pdf";
        string pathToOrginalPdf;
        pathToOrginalPdf = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pdfName);
        if (selected == null || select.length == 0)
        {
            List<string> ss = new List<string>();
            QuickPDFAX0816.PDFLibrary qp = new PDFLibrary();
            qp.UnlockKey("xxxxxcodexxxx");
            qp.LoadFromFile(pathToOrginalPdf, "");
            int n = qp.PageCount();
            for (int t = 1; t < n + 1; t++)
            {
                ss.Add(t.ToString()); 
            }
            selected = ss.ToArray(); 
        }
        return Common.pdfUtilites.PrintSelectedPages(pathToOrginalPdf, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()) + ".pdf", selected.ToList(), freeEditFields, PostIts);
    }
```

My utilities code

```
 public static string PrintSelectedPages(string pathToPDF, string docName, List<string> selectedPages, List<FreeEditField> freeEdits, List<PostItNote> PostIts)
    {
        QuickPDFAX0816.PDFLibrary qp = new PDFLibrary();
        qp.UnlockKey("xxxcodexxxx");
        if (qp.LoadFromFile(pathToPDF, "") == 1)
        {
            string pages = "";
            foreach (string s in selectedPages)
            {
                pages = pages + s + ",";
            }
            qp.ExtractPageRanges(pages);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            sb.Append("var pp=this.getPrintParams();"); 
            sb.Append("pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.automatic;"); 
            sb.Append("this.print(pp);");

            qp.SetOpenActionJavaScript("var pp=this.getPrintParams();this.print(pp);"); 
            qp.SaveToFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../TmpForDownloads/print" + docName));
            qp = null;

            string doc = AddEditFieldData(freeEdits, "../TmpForDownloads/print" + docName, selectedPages);
            doc = AddPostItNotes(PostIts, "../TmpForDownloads/print" + docName, selectedPages);
            return doc;
        }
        else
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

My link to my problems.

http://www.agflipbooks.com/books/book.aspx?bookid=301

Here is what is going on. 
I go to click the print button on the right bottom icon that looks like a printer.
I click print all dialog box comes up shows system process after about 2 to 3 minutes. 
A second box comes up saying initializing then noting. I let it sit for about 15 minutes and nothing just frozen.

Click on the link above and see for yourself.
I go to the directory TmpForDownloas and the pdf is there I click on the pdf and all files are created.

AddPostItNotes add any postits that was added to the pages on the books the same with AddEditFieldData if there are field with text it is added to the pdfs.

any help will be appreciated?

I all so have this as well.

```
function printResult(res) {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        $.browser.safari = /safari/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        $.browser.mozilla = /mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        var time = 3000; 
        var OSName = "Unknown OS";

        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = "Windows";
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = "MacOS";
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") != -1) OSName = "UNIX";
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = "Linux";

        $("#pdfPrintDialog").dialog({ modal: true, width: 640, height: 500,
            open: function () {
                var objectTag = "<object data='" + res + "#view=Fit&toolbar=1' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%'><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. No worries, just <a href='../TmpDownloads/testpdf.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>"
                $("#pdfArea").html(objectTag);
            },
            buttons: {
                "Done": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed it was a caching problem with images to pdf. I decrease the